# I want to create a searchbar but be able to hide data

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a search bar with data but not have all the data shown at once time.I want to hide the data until something is searched such as dog then be able to click that item.

I am having trouble pasting my information to this search site.

Comment: You must attach additional information and a code so we can help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.